# grep out condition and add the values of the grep value

Tags: find, grep, awk

I have a scenario that a csv file has the values of :

```
abcd FAILURE 7

abcd SUCCESS 12

efgh SUCCESS 3

efgh FAILURE 5

mnop SUCCESS 6

mnop SUCCESS 4

abcd FAILURE 5

efgh SUCCESS 2

mnop SUCCESS 1

abcd FAILURE 7

mnop SUCCESS 3

abcd FAILURE 5
```

Initial grep with abcd/efgh/mnop with failure or success condition then i need a value of the matching conditions addition

i need the required output like this please help me

for example :

```
abcd FAILURE 7

abcd FAILURE 5

abcd FAILURE 7

abcd FAILURE 5

--------------------

abcd FAILURE **24**

abcd SUCCESS 12

------------------

abcd SUCCESS **12**
```

but i dont want to give any static string in condition.

thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont know which string consist in the csv file so cannot give the static string in the grep

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -c` option to count occurences of a search-string. echo outputs the text and uses a sub-shell for the grep count.

```
echo "abcd FAILURE $(grep -c "abcd FAILURE" filename)" 
echo "abcd SUCCESS $(grep -c "abcd SUCCESS" filename)"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like this:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    fail = suc = 0
}
$2 == "FAILURE" {
    fail += $3
    next
}
$2 == "SUCCESS" {
    suc += $3
}
END {
    printf "%s:%s\n%s:%s\n", "SUCCESS",suc,"FAILURE",fail
}' inputFile
```

#### Output with you file:

```
SUCCESS:31
FAILURE:29
```